# Can´t get attributes from ElementRef.nativeElement in Ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

First I´m going to explain what I want to do. I have an `ion-textarea` in a form and I want to resize height depending on the content. I´m still a newbie with ionic2 and I´m trying to do things right and Learn so I have thought the best way to do this creates a directive and then use it within `ion-textarea`.

Basically what I need is:
- get scrollHeight from `textarea`
- set `textarea` height to `scrollHeight` value

I know how to set height value with Renderer, my problem is getting scrollHeight (or any other attribute value).

This is my testing code:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer} from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[textarea-autosize]',
})

export class TextareaAutosize{


    private el: HTMLElement;
    constructor(private element:ElementRef, private render:Renderer){
    }
    ngAfterViewInit(){

        this.el = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('textarea'); //I have checked without querySelector too
        console.log(this.element.nativeElement.style); //this return CSSStyleDeclaration with all empty properties 
        console.log(this.el.scrollHeight); //this return always 0
        console.log(this.el); //this return the html textarea code
        this.render.setElementStyle(this.el, 'height', 100 + 'px'); //this set height to 100px
    }
}
```

I googled a lot and I found people getting attributes like me, therefore, I´m doing something wrong or maybe what I want to have to be done by another way.